# How to stream music from echonest?

Tags: streaming, enyo

Now I am using `enyo.js`. 
I want to stream music from `echonest`. Now i am able to get the ids of the songs.

I want to stream the music.

Answer (score 0):

More than likely you can just use an HTML 5  tag for this.  You'll need to investigate their API more fully to find out if there's another request you need to make once you have the ID, or if the ID is a URL to an audio file, just make an  tag and set that as the source.

Comment: I didn't get.Actually m getting data like this....http://developer.echonest.com/api/v4/song/search?api_key=N6E4NIOVYMTHNDM8J&style=rock&min_danceability=0.65&min_tempo=140&results=5

Comment: This looks to me like you aren't calling the correct part of the API to get back the "audio" link.  For example, if you look at their playlist API methods, one of the return examples shows an object and buried in there is the "audio" property which is a string/URL to the location of the song.

I'm not sure I can offer much more help on this one.  You might need to look through their support/docs for more help on getting the data you need.